# X11 exception in Java

Tags: java, awt, headless

Motive of adding AWT: To add a dialog box in front end to allow users to save file at desired location .

Code is working fine when I am running in local (with Tomcat7.0 in eclipse) and failing when running on Virtual Server with Tomact 7.0 JDK 1.7 and throwing awt headless exception.

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which is required
```

Tried the below fix but still not working

```java
System.setProperty(“java.awt.headless”, “false”); 
System.out.println(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless());
```

Please help how this can be resolved in Java .. In Unix server X11forwarding is enabled

**Option 1**: Tried headless value as true and getting the same Headless exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.java.Sample#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/manage-servlet.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.java.Sample]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.awt.HeadlessException:
```

**Option 2**: Added the headless value as false and got below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.java.Sample#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/manage-servlet.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.java.Sample]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
```

Note: here changed display variable to `DISPLAY:0` but still failed

**Option 3**: Added display variable as false and added the command false in startup script also then also it failed with below exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195) java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102) java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81) java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:467)
```

Swing Code in java file:

```java
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(); fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Users"); int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this); if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(fileToSave.getAbsolutePath()); AUDIT.info("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
```

I am fed up with this headless exception handling and not getting a way to solve this.

Comment: If it's not possible to resolve this ..plz suggest how to create save dialog box in JSP by accessing a variable in java .

Answer (score 0):

Same error I also got when Java UI being loaded. Below command fixed the issue on my CentOS 7.x version.

export DISPLAY=:0

Comment: Tnq fr suggesting but it's not working for me 

Comment: I am adding export in serenv.sh file .... Display needs to be set in any other file?